# Using the result of Solve as a function of parameters

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

I am trying to find b2 maximising a function I named 'EG1EUB'. And 'EG1EUBb2' is the frist order condition. Based on my understanding, Solve gave me a single solution saying that b2 is the second root. And I believe that '#' is indicating b2. So I want to take this second root as a new function of thetab1 and thetab2 which are parameters of my objective function. However I couldn't find out how to do that. Below is what happened.

```
Solve[EG1EUBb2[b2, thetab1,thetab2] == 0 && (1/4) < b2 < thetab2, b2, Reals, Assumptions ->(1/2) <=thetab1 <=1 &&(1/2) <=thetab2 <=1]
```

The result came out like
[image]

I tried something like this. But it is not working.

```
b2[thetab1_, thetab2_]:=Root[-899+2160 thetab1+922 thetab2+(76-4320 thetab1+8000 thetab2) #1+(-4800-9600 thetab2) SuperscriptBox["#1", "2"]+6400 SuperscriptBox["#1", "3"]&,2]
```

Below is my notebook that I am working on.
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/5542bdbc-ddaa-44c4-bc8d-0f46a2b0f8a0

Comment: Your code has several issues. For the start, you must replace `#1` with a variable name in the definition of `b2`.

Comment: @polfosol So what you meant is that '#1' is not 'b2' but something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

"But it is not working." In what sense? How are you trying to use it? It evaluates fine.

```
b2[thetab1_, thetab2_] := 
 Root[-899 + 2160 thetab1 + 
    922 thetab2 + (76 - 4320 thetab1 + 8000 thetab2) #1 + (-4800 - 
       9600 thetab2) #1^2 + 6400 #1^3 &, 2]

Plot3D[b2[thetab1, thetab2],
 {thetab1, 1/2, 1}, {thetab2, 1/2, 1},
 AxesLabel -> {"thetab1", "thetab2", "b2"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem was due to the fact that I didn't clear what I did previously. Btw could you help me to confrim this: 'b2 = #1'? This is basically my first project to work with Mathematica. So I'm not confident with these notations.

Comment: `b2` is your function. If the slot where filled with `b2` it would be recursive. The slot is the unnamed argument of a pure function that defines a polynomial whose root is the `Root` expression. You don't fill it, it is just used to define the polynomial.

Comment: `y = Root[#^3 - 3 # + 4 &, 1]` is just an exact number (the first root of the pure function shown). Its numeric value is approximately `y // N`; its algebraic representation is `y // ToRadicals`. In your definition of `b2` the pure function defining the root has two parameters in addition to the unnamed variable.